# Counting negative values in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a list a of data points read from file in gnuplot. Is there any way to count the number of negative values in the list, and store the result as a variable?

I could not find anything upon a quick Google search.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Actually, at SO we expect a little bit more own research effort than a "quick" Google search. Have you searched the gnuplot homepage and SO? What have you tried? How does your data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to extract the desired number, it depends how you want to use this number further.

1. count the negative values with `stats` (check `help stats`) and a comparison. `$2<0` returns `1` or `0`. Hence, the variable `STATS_sum` will contain the number of negative values.

or alternatively

2. count the negative values during plotting using the ternary operator (check `help ternary`). Plot the number into your plot using plotting style `with labels`.

**Script:**

```
### count negative values
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(rand(0)*10-1) w table
unset table

set key noautotitle
set xzeroaxis lt -1

stats $Data u ($2<0) nooutput
print sprintf("Negative values: %d", STATS_sum)

plot c=0 $Data u 1:($2<0?c=c+1:0,$2) w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "Data", \
         '+' u (0):(10):(sprintf("Negative values: %d",c)) every ::::0 w labels offset 0,-1
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
Negative values: 6
```

[image]